# Python statement to print specific row in .csv depending on week number

Tags: python, date, csv, if-statement

I have a .csv file that has data in 5 columns. The 5th column is the date as a numbered week. I would like to print the other 4 columns data in an object on a desktop depending on the current week number. For example week 01 has 1 in column 1, 2 in column 2, 3 in column 3, and 4 in column 4. I want to print in order 1,2, 3, 4 in an object. Once the week 01 is over, I want it to change to the data for week 02. In column 1 the data is now 5, column 2 is now 6, etc. I have been trying to find an if statement that will work but nothing I have found works.

I am new to python with some background in coding. I can't figure out the proper if statement or is there a better function to use? Thank you.

This is where I am so far:

```
from datetime import date

import wx
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'win.py')
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()

import csv

import time
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
"""
Read a csv.DictReader
"""
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    for column in reader:
        if(column["Date"])==(time.strftime("%U")):
            print(column["Column 1"])
            print(column["Column 2"])
            print(column["Column 3"])
            print(column["Column 4"])


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("data.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_dict_reader(f_obj)
```

A sample of my .csv is:

```
Column 1     Column 2    Column 3    Column 4    Date
  1            2           3           4           1
  5            6           7           8           2
  9            10          11          12          3
```

An output I want is: 
If week 1 print:

```
1
2
3
4
```

If week 2 print:

```
5
6
7
8
```

I want them printed in a box that resides on the desktop. When the week changes I want it to automatically change to the next weeks data.

Thank you.

sdruch

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please clarify your question, especially according to the posting guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Among other things, please show sample data from your input file and samples of the required output.  Among other things, the result you expect is confusing: "print" is a command to send data to an output channel; an "object" is an internal data structure of your design.
Also, you state that you want to print in descending order, but you've described an ascending order.

Comment: Please could you edit your question (press the `edit` button) to add a small sample of your input, and also what your expected output should be.

Comment: I have added a sample and an expected output. Thank you.

Comment: So what is the triggering event, are you indicating that when the time-date advances you want the file to be checked and the right values pulled from the file and displayed. This is not too hard but you need to have two functions I think, one to check the date time and two to read the file and pull the right row and display it.  I guess you need to hold onto the current week and when it changes then open the file and find the appropriate values

Comment: I think you need to break this down into chunks the first chunk would be how to tell that the week has changed.  The second chunk would be, given the change in the week how do I select the right values from the csv file.  The problem I think is easier to see when framed this way - if I am correct on my interpretation of your question

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of changing and looking I got something that will work until the next week. I will have to see if I can find a refresh script or something. I am posting the final code I got working. If anyone knows of a simpler way to make this work, please let me know.

```
import csv
import time
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var0 = StringVar()
var1 = StringVar()
var2 = StringVar()
var3 = StringVar()

label0 = Label(root, textvariable=var0, relief=RAISED)
label1 = Label(root, textvariable=var1, relief=RAISED)
label2 = Label(root, textvariable=var2, relief=RAISED)
label3 = Label(root, textvariable=var3, relief=RAISED)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):

reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
for column in reader:
 if(column["Week"])==(time.strftime("%U")):
  var0.set(column["Column1"])
  var1.set(column["Column2"])
  var2.set(column["Column3"])
  var3.set(column["Column4"])

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("Data.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_dict_reader(f_obj)

label0.pack()
label1.pack()
label2.pack()
label3.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This is working to give me the data I want to display from the .csv file. Like I said I will need to see if there is a refresh or something that will make it automatically change when the new week occurs.

Thank you

sdruch